# Why are there only 8 Martyrs in the Tisha b'av kinnos

Tags: number, names, song-poetry, tisha-bav, martyr

The kinna on Tisha b'av says there are 10 Martyrs, but only 8 are named.
In the Yom Kippur version, however, all 10 are mentioned. Why are 2 missing from Tisha b'av?

Comment: Perhaps there is a fundamental difference between the messages of Tisha Ba'av and Yom Kippur that requires one to fully discuss all 10 Martyrs on Y"K while a more cursory overview is considered appropriate for Tb"A? Or maybe it was just different authors writing their respective piyutim and we can't really infer from one to the other...

Comment: If so, the T.A. One should just say it is about martyrs, nos specifying that there are 10

Comment: Why can't the author explicitly reference a cultural memory without recalling all of it? You're implying that the author of a piyut "must" write in a certain way, and I'm not sure there's any basis to saying that...